# Variable not found when using a Tensorflow session in another function

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask

I am creating a Flask app and I want to restore a tensorflow session with it's variables only once and use it on various routes to make predictions but it doesn't seem to work.I created a class whose constructor restores the interactive session and it's variables,the class also contains a function named predict which tries to predict the outcome using the interactive session described in the constructor.The following code is how i initialize the object to be shared among all routes.

```
class MyServer(Flask):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyServer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.testClass=TestClass()
app = MyServer(__name__)
```

Here is an example of the route I used

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    size_dict=app.testClass.test(saveName)
    return jsonify(size_dict)
```

But this throws the following error

```
ValueError: Variable Net_WT/block1/bn does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?
```

But if I initialize the object and use it in the same route it works

Comment: How are you serving the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to answer my own question but I found a solution,in the constructor of the TestClass I added `self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()` after restoring the session and variables.